# Unexpected behavior in spatstat hyperframes?

Tags: r, spatstat

I am trying to make spatstat [`hyperframe`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/spatstat/docs/hyperframe)s from lists hyperframes containing of `owin` objects (or any spatstat objects for that matter), but face unexpected behavior when using `rbind.hyperframe` command in `do.call` to bind the lists into a larger `hyperframe`:

```
library(spatstat)
circles <- list(large = disc(10), medium = disc(5), small = disc(1))

circle.list <- lapply(names(circles), function(k) hyperframe(name = k, circle = circles[[k]]))
circle.list

# [[1]]
# Hyperframe:
#   name circle
# 1 large (owin)
```

At this point the list works as it should. `owin` objects are separately in each cell of the listed hyperframes:

```
circle.list[[1]]$circle

#window: polygonal boundary
#enclosing rectangle: [-10, 10] x [-10, 10] units
```

Next I use `do.call` command to `rbind` the hyperframes:

```
circle.hyperframe <- do.call(rbind.hyperframe, circle.list)
circle.hyperframe

# Hyperframe:
#    name circle
# 1  large (list)
# 2 medium (list)
# 3  small (list)
```

Now the circles are lists (what they essentially are in spatstat), but it seems that all of them are bound together:

```
names(circle.hyperframe[1,]$circle)
# [1] "type"   "xrange" "yrange" "bdry"   "units"  "type"   "xrange" "yrange" "bdry"  
# [10] "units"  "type"   "xrange" "yrange" "bdry"   "units"
```

Note triplicate names for one cell.

My code relies on lists and I would very much like to be able to bind these lists together into a larger `hyperframe`. **Is there a way around this behavior, i.e how to rbind the hyperframes without binding the cells in 'circle' column?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this behaviour is unexpected, and I don't know the explanation at the moment. There is a simple solution for your example, but I'm not sure it is useful in a more general setting where you probably need it:

```
library(spatstat)
circles <- list(large = disc(10), medium = disc(5), small = disc(1))
circle.hyperframe <- hyperframe(name=names(circles), circle=circles)
```

Comment: Your solution actually solves one particular problem I had, although I had to modify the angle a little bit. I did not consider adding lists directly as columns, because I was stuck thinking how it would work with data.frames. Thanks!